# Возможно ли у блока div вместо фона css поставить видео backgroung?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Дан блок. Высота 200px, ширина 700px. Допустим, у блока фон #000 (черный). Как сделать так, чтобы вместо черного фона было видео фоновое какое-нибудь? Размер блока фиксированный.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать div с position:relative, включающий в себя div с видеофайлом и div с контентом с position: absolute и разными z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Очень простая реализация :)

Демо http://goo.gl/ghLC7l

Архив http://rghost.ru/58398632